# Linux python read output from a running python script

Tags: python, linux, logging, output, autorun

I have a python script running as service in linux (also as autorun), and it does plenty of output!
How can I read this output when the program is already running?

Maybe I could log all the output into a file but then I would have to open and refresh the file all the time when new output is logged!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is also possible to implement tail from the python side, which is basically a continuous reading of it. The code snippet to make this work can be found here:

http://code.activestate.com/recipes/157035-tail-f-in-python/

Additionally, if you use the append mode of file writing instead of the write method you can continuously output.

Scrapy also uses the concept of pipelines which allow for a lot of the same functionality. Here's an example of some scrapy code you might use to do the same thing:

```
class JsonWriterPipeline(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.file = (open(filepath, 'a'))
    def process_item(self, item, spider):
        self.file.write(json.dumps(dict(item)) + '\n')
        return item
```

Answer (score 3):

Well, when it comes to the second paragraph of the question, in the shell you can do:

```
tail -f logfile.log
```

which automaticly refreshes when file is updated, so under Linux that's a working solution.

Comment: +1. There are also things like [`multitail`](http://www.vanheusden.com/multitail/) (to view multiple files by wildcard, separately or merged, filtered and colorized, etc.), [`glogg`](http://glogg.bonnefon.org) (to watch the file in a nice GUI window), etc. There's no reason to build something yourself when it already exists.